# Regex to parse hash url from HTML content

Tags: javascript, regex, hash

I have regex to parse all hash url in HTML content.

```
/(\#)([^\s]+")/g
```

HTML content will be as

```
Some text <a href="#some-hash1">some link</a>some content <a href="#some-hash2">some link1</a>
```

Expected is

```
#some-hash1, #some-hash2
```

But current regex is returning as (ending double come along with hash):

```
#some-hash1", #some-hash2"
```

I am unable to understand why its come along with double quotes. Any suggestion that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move double quote out the brackets:

```
(\#)([^\s]+)"
```

See how it works: https://regex101.com/r/fmrDyu/1

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use regex for this because it's overkill and because you can simply loop through the anchors pulling the value of their hrefs...

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
var hrefs = [];

anchors.forEach(function(e){

 hrefs.push(e.getAttribute('href'));

});

console.log(hrefs);
```

```html
<a href="link 1">link 1</a>
<a href="link 2">link 2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use non-capturing parenthesis,

```
/(\#)([^\s]+(?="))/g
```

**DEMO**

```js
 var z = 'Some text <a href="#some-hash1">some link</a>some content <a href="#some-hash2">some link1</a>';
console.log(    z.match(/(\#)([^\s]+(?="))/g) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are looking at the content of $2 for your result.

If so, the problem is the *"* inside the second capture group. Changing `/(\#)([^\s]+")/g` to `/(\#)([^\s]+")/g` results in the correct result.

I suggest joining the capture groups. Then `/(\#[^\s]+)"/g` will return `$1=>#some-hash1, #some-hash2`

Since $1 will always just return *#*, I suppose you trim it off elsewhere in your program, so perhaps you should use `/\#([^\s]+)"/g` which will return `some-hash1, some-hash2` without the *#*